# MVVM Basic Concept Understanding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've started working on an application that allows the user to enter some data in different textboxes and then these data are serialized in an XML format, but it seems that I've understood the MVVM concept completely wrong because I've tried to serialize the ViewModel and one of my work colleagues said that is an incorrect way to do things and I should serialize the MODEL.

The "incorrect" implementation:

```
public class ExampleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private double lowerRange;

    public double LowerRange
    {
        get { return lowerRange; }
        set
        {
            lowerRange = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private double upperRange;

    public double UpperRange
    {
        get { return upperRange; }
        set
        {
            upperRange = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

According to my colleague, serializing this is wrong, but then how should look my MODEL (actually this is the question)
This is correct?

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    public double LowerRange { get; set; }
    public double UpperRange { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ExampleModel model;
    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        model = new ExampleModel();
    }

    private double lowerRange;

    public double LowerRange
    {
        get { return model.LowerRange; }
        set
        {
            model.LowerRange = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private double upperRange;

    public double UpperRange
    {
        get { return model.UpperRange; }
        set
        {
            model.UpperRange = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Or this is complety overhead? If you can provide me a meaningful example, I'll be grateful.
Also, I've seen some people that use "RaisePropertyChanged()" inside a MODEL, is this correct? that this model because a ViewModel, right?

Comment: "application that allows the user to enter some data in different textboxes and then these data are serialized in an XML format" -  if that is all what application does, then IMO single class ExampleModel would suffice. I don't see anything what requires RaisePropertyChanged

Comment: Ask your colleagues for a reference for their claim that serializing a view model is "wrong". Be aware that you may have valid MVVM without an explicit model class. Your view model can *be* the model.

Comment: One additional note: I don't think there is anything wrong with a model class inheriting `ViewModelBase`. That way you can have your Model be a property of your ViewModel, but you can bind to it directly - while still maintaining the decoupling between GUI and data. At least that is how I tend to do it.

Comment: @Clemens, I thought it is reverse -"model can be the viewmodel" - since viewmodel has secondary role

Comment: What I mean is that both are represented by the same class/object. For me this has always been a view model that is a model, not the other way round, but that is just a matter of taste.

Comment: @Clemens, that matters if you keep classes in separate projects - ViewsProject, ViewModelsProject, ModelsProject. in that structure model can serve as VM and be referenced by other VM, but not reverse

Comment: I would usually have a model and a viewmodel.  I often copy properties from one to the other and back using automapper.  This way the model is discrete from the viewmodel. I can have whatever properties suit the view on my viewmodel and whatever suit storage/retrieval in the model.

Comment: The point of MVVM is to have a Model-View-ViewModel, hence the name - period. If you decide to drop the ViewModel because your application is very small then it is technically no MVVM anymore. Matter of fact. The pattern is very concrete on how to structure the application. If sometimes the Model class is a ViewModel class and sometimes not is a really messy architecture. You can do what ever you think is right, but recommending such practice to somebody who is learning the pattern is not right. He is already confused. Instead you could explain to him how to implement his example properly.

Comment: @Vesa95 "Model" is a component not a class. The "Model" comprises a set of class that implement the business logic and business entities. The business entities usually hold the relevant data. the "View Model" is only presenting it to the "View". The data format that the "View Model" exposes to the "View" is usually not in the format that the business logic uses or persists. Therefore you usually persist the business entities (or data models). This is what you do if you want to persist the application's state. The "View Model" will get the persisted data from the "Model" API.

Comment: If you persist "View Model" data, then you must separate it from the application data.  In your case I guess you meant to persist application data, so you are only interested in "Model" data. Persistence or IO of any kind generally takes place in the "Model", anyway. "Model" is the component that operates on the data (business logic), because it knows the business rules. The "View Model" does not know the business rules. "View Model" prepares data for presentation and exposes it to the view and sends user modified data back to the "Model".

Answer (score -1):

Following my comment above, here is how I tend to do this:

```
public class ExampleModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private double _lowerRange;
    private double _upperRange;

    public double LowerRange 
    {
        get { return _lowerRange; }
        set
        {
            _lowerRange = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public double UpperRange 
    {
        get { return _upperRange; }
        set
        {
            _upperRange= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class ExampleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ExampleModel model;
    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        Model = new ExampleModel();
    }

    // this is only needed if you change your complete model
    // and need to update the change on the UI
    public ExampleModel Model
    {
        get { return model; }
        set
        {
            model = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you change your `ViewModelBase` class to something like the one shown [here](https://github.com/TheRealRolandDeschain/DesignPatternsMVVMExample/blob/master/MVVMExample/ViewModel/ViewModelBase.cs), you can simplify the property getters/setters a bit to the following for example:

```
public ExampleModel Model
{
    get { return model; }
    set { SetProperty<ExampleModel >(ref model, value); }
}
```

Comment: He is learning MVVM and nothing else. MVVM is a design pattern and not a best practice convention. You follow the pattern or not. If not, it is no MVVM. And "Model" is a component not a class. The "Model" comprises a set of class that implement the business logic and business entities.

Comment: "MVVM is a design pattern and not a best practice convention." - Well that is exactlly what design patterns are: a best practice convention one should follow to have a good code structure. Sure, the question is always how strict one follows a certain pattern in an actual program, but I don't see what the issue is with the example above (or why it shouldn't be MVVM). It is pretty much out of a [textbook](https://www.rheinwerk-verlag.de/c-sharp-8-mit-visual-studio-2019-das-umfassende-handbuch/), only adapted to fit OPs question.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. You don't have to follow any pattern exactly. But the term design pattern is well defined. If you don't follow a certain pattern but just use it as a raw guide than you are defacto not implementing the pattern but have created a variation. That's all I'm saying. Binding tje view to the model is not textbook. I agree that it can reduce the effort and complexity in small applications by sacrificing the extra layer of decoupling view and model - the extra layer MVVM explicitly introduces for a purpose. Then this is not MVVM but a less powerful structure inspired by MVVM.